# Distribution graph in HighCharts

Tags: javascript, graph, charts, highcharts

I have some data, which is the time in seconds (from people completing a workout). I want to graph these times in HighCharts, but I feel like I'm going about this all wrong. Right now I'm having to fill in the spaces between values with 0's. Also, note that some people finished in the exact same times

```
//Time in seconds, already ordered
var rawData = [183, 189, 195, 237, 256, 298, 306, 314, 328, 330, 330, 330, 338, 364, 370, 411, 411, 458, 474, 513, 513, 566, 572, 574, 600];

//Get the smallest & largest values.
//This is simple since it's already ordered
var min = rawData[0];
var max = rawData[rawData.length - 1];

//Now fill in the missing places in the data.
//Count how many items have the exact same value
var graphData = [];
for (var i = min; i <= max; i++) {
  graphData.push(_.filter(rawData,function(m){
    return m === i;
  }).length);
}
```

I know this can't be the best way to do what I want, and I know it has some bugs with it.  Can anyone suggest a better way of doing this?

### Demo: http://codepen.io/chrismbarr/pen/epGGYX?editors=001

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do that. You only need to create a 2D array with the x and y values, eg.

```
var graphData = [];
for (var i in rawData) {
    graphData.push([rawData[i], _.filter(rawData,function(m){
    return m === rawData[i];
  }).length]);
}
```

which creates an array like

```
[
    [183, 1],
    [189, 1],
    [195, 1],
    [237, 1],
    [256, 1],
    [298, 1], 
    // so on
    [330, 3],
    [330, 3],
    [330, 3],
    // ...
]
```

**Update**

another option is

```
var graphData = [];
for (var i = min; i <= max; i++) {
    var ocurrences = _.filter(rawData, function(m){
        return m === i;
    }).length;
    if (ocurrences > 0) {
       graphData.push([i,ocurrences]);
    }
}
```

which creates

```
[
    [183, 1],
    [189, 1],
    [195, 1],
    [237, 1],
    [256, 1],
    [298, 1], 
    // so on
    [330, 3],
    // ...
]
```

Both options work, you don't have to worry about the repeated items in the first resulting array since Highcharts draws the bars exactly in the same position, so you won't notice the difference.

**Demo** http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RWLjed?editors=001

Comment: Perfect, thank you!  I totally forgot about the nested arrays in HighCharts.